# How do I limit the number of rows affected from the query?

Tags: 8, database

In my custom module for Drupal 8, I am using the following code.

```
$query = $this->connection->select('node_field_data', 'nf_data');
$result = $query->execute();
```

I want to get the first 500 rows. I tried with `$query->limit(50)`, but that gives the following error.

> Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Select::limit()

What is the correct code to get the first 500 rows?

Answer (score 20):

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/class/Select/8.6.x

```
$query->range(0, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

The object returned from `$this->connection->select()` is an object of a class that extends [`\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/class/Select/8.6.x) (not [`\Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.6.x) which is for entity queries). In your case, since you are using MySQL as database engine, that class specifically is [`\Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Driver%21mysql%21Select.php/class/Select/8.6.x), as the error you quoted says.

The method you are looking for is [`Select::range()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3Arange/8.6.x).

You are confusing it with [`PagerSelectExtender::limit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21PagerSelectExtender.php/function/PagerSelectExtender%3A%3Alimit/8.6.x), used to limit the number of elements per page, and implemented from the [`PagerSelectExtender`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21PagerSelectExtender.php/class/PagerSelectExtender/8.6.x) class. To use this method, you need to add a pager to the query, though.